# How to dynamically pass object type to <>?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to use a method to create an empty document in a collection and get its id from MongoDB. I was thinking about using same method for 2 different types of object types. For example:

```
public async Task<string> CreateObject (object x) 
{ 
  Type objectType = x.GetType();
  _context.Database.
  GetCollection<objectType>("CollectionName").
  InsertOneAsync(x); 

  return x; 

 }
```

But this doesn't work as GetCollection<> will work only with entities or models thats defined already in the application and refusing to take object type dynamically according to my code. I dunno if its bad programming but is it possible to attain this or just stupid to try this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you use [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_GetCollection_3.htm) overload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but what if you make your method a generic one like

```
public async Task<string> CreateObject<T> (T x) 
{ 
  _context.Database.
  GetCollection<T>(nameof(T)).InsertOneAsync(x); 
  return x; 
}
```

Comment: @Neo You'll need to modify your calling code in conjunction with this solution to look like this: `var result = await CreateObject<MyType1>(myObject1);`

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use something like `dynamic` type?

```
_context.Database.
  GetCollection<dynamic>("CollectionName").
  InsertOneAsync(x);
```

Or you can use the `BsonDocument` class as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an empty document into a collection and get back an id in which the database server assigned it you can do the following:

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
await client.DropDatabaseAsync(database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName);
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");

var newDocument = new BsonDocument();
await collection.InsertOneAsync(newDocument);

var id = newDocument["_id"].AsObjectId;

Console.WriteLine($"_id is '{id}'");
```